# To get FTS3 support in SQLite3 using Ruby, do you have to manually compile sqlite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sqlite3-ruby, fts3

I've got a web app where I'd like to user FTS3 functionality of SQLite3.

I've got the SQLite3-ruby v1.2.5 gem installed. I'd like to have FTS3 support, and I know, due to trying to create an FTS3 table, that it doesn't come with it.

Do I need to compile the gem/sqlite3 myself in order to get this support? Is there a seprate gem I should be using?

Comment: I'll even settle for fts2 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've answered my own question, and I believe that the answer is essentially "yes", with a but:

Yes you can compile yourself, if you really want to go to crazy lengths. It seems that there may be other plugins, and other things you can install to do full-text search.

What these are, I'm still looking into.

Comment: I've decided to go with a 3rd part gem, "acts_as_xapian", which now that I've used it I would highly recommend it to others.